# Why does the mirror modifier doesn't work even though I extruded along the X-Axis

Tags: modifiers, mirror, axis

[image]

I have one weird problem. I have an abject that is extruded along the X axis (pressing 'e' and 'x')
But when I add the mirror modifier it is slightly off. On one end it is overlapping and on the other end it is far away (excuse my bad English). Does someone know what the problem is or how I can fix whatever is happening there? [image]

Comment: That is probably because you have rotated your object in edit mode.

Comment: Hm, maybe I am missing something @Nxdhin2005 it looks straight when compared to the line right above it (background)  only the mirrored version doesn't  look straight compared to the background lines

Comment: Try applying rotation by Ctrl+A and click on rotation.Does that help?

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 After normal rotating it might be mirrored somewhat evenly but therefor the "Origin-Object" is now not straight along the x axis anymore. The Shortcut Control+A is making loop cuts for me, maybe different settings

Comment: you need to apply the rotation in Object mode, not Edit mode

Comment: @moonboots I doesn't make a difference if the object is rotated in object mode and the mirror modifier is applied the mirror effect is still the same as before. Even though it seems like the weird effect is only happening with the objects I already have in the file. I don't want to redo it all so maybe there is still a chance of fixing it

Comment: once the rotation is applied, redo your extrusion, it will be easier to work if you're aligned with the global axis